# Get access token and subscribe on real-time updates php

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

I am developing an application for which I need to subscribe to facebook real-time updates. Unfortunately, I am getting an error while trying to execute the code for the subscription. The error is the following:

> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#100) The parameter object is
>   required thrown in /var/www/******/php-sdk/base_facebook.php on line
>   1039

My code is the following:

```
$parameters = array();
$parameters[scope] = '****';
$parameters[redirect_uri] = '*****';

$config = array();
$config['appId'] = '111111111111111111';
$config['secret'] = '*****************';
$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
if($user_id)
{
$user['access_token'] = $facebook->getAccessToken();


$sub_param = array('access_token' => $user['access_token'],
            'object' => 'user',
            'fields' => 'feed',
            'callback_url' => $parameters[redirect_uri].'callBackUrl.php',
            'verify_token' => '********'
            );
    $newSubs = $facebook->api('/'.$config['appId'].'/subscriptions', 'POST',  $param); 

}
else
{
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($parameters);
    echo "<script> top.location.href='" . $loginUrl . "'</script>";
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: And which line is 1039 in your code sample?

Answer (score 1):

You get that error when you aren't sending any params in the post body (or if you pass something like a json encoded object rather than postfields).

Did you mean to create an array called $sub_param but then pass $param to $facebook->api?

Answer (score 1):

To subscribe to facebook real-time updates, you need a application access token instead of user access token.

Please refer to Facebook Dev blog - http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/01/31/how-to--subscribing-to-data-changes-using-the-real-time-updates-api/

Also below link is also helpful.
RTU tutorial - http://www.fb-developers.info/tech/fb_dev/tutorial/bytopic/realtime_upd_01.php